# npm run no funciona en vuejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js, npm, webpack

Este es el error

```
 1. > $ npm run dev

    > vuejs@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Leonel\Desktop\vuejs
    > webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! syscall spawn % SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;
    npm ERR! file % SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;
    npm ERR! path % SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;
    npm ERR! errno ENOENT
    npm ERR! vuejs@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
    npm ERR! spawn % SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the vuejs@1.0.0 dev script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:


    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Leonel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-26T22_27_15_443Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Intenta borrando `node_modules` y despues `npm i`

Comment: ya probé y no funciono

Comment: probá con esta https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/714#issuecomment-462357836 o alguna de las otras opciones que tienen votos en ese hilo. Si nada de eso funciona, mostranos que tenés en package.json

Comment: El dev debe estar definido dentro del script en el package.jsob

Comment: Como dicen arriba si nada funciona podría ser útil mostrar la información de C:\Users\Leonel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-26T22_27_15_443Z-debug.log

Comment: Has mirado el log?